# When is null useful?

Tags: java, null, garbage-collection

Nowadays we have Guava's `Optional` and builder pattern. Every book/blog says to avoid nulls. We have to use them when dealing with legacy code or protocols that explicitly require it. But are there any other use cases when it's useful or when it's the best option?

Comment: Worth noting that Java 8 has its own [`Optional`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is useful for uninitialised variables.  Whether it is useful as a valid value is another question which depends on your programming model.  For example, if you have a model where you aim to produce little or no garbage, Optional is not an option and `null` produces no garbage.

In extreme cases, your target might be to produce 1 GB/hour or as low as 1 GB per day of garbage.  This allows you to run for a day or a week without a minor collection.

In "normal" Java programming, a lack of use of one of these wrappers it likely to be due to laziness.  It is more effort, for little perceived gain (as I never intend to write NPE into my code)  What would be useful is tools like your IDE filling in this code for you. e.g. IntelliJ will tell you if you have a value which could be `null` and cn introduce runtime checks.

Comment: I like _`Optional` is not an option_. P.S. the Java 8 `Optional` produces less garbage.